# The actual executor memory does not match the executoy-memory I set

Tags: apache-spark

I hava a spark2.0.1 cluster with 1 Master(slaver1) and 2 worker(slaver2,slaver3),every machine has 2GB RAM.when I run the command
`./bin/spark-shell --master spark://slaver1:7077 --executor-memory 500m`
when I check the executor memory in the web (slaver1:4040/executors/). I found it is 110MB.
[image: image description here]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The memory you are talking about is Storage memory Actually Spark Divides the memory [Called `Spark Memory`] into 2 Region First is `Storage Memory` and Second is `Execution Memory`

The Total Memory can Be calculated by this Formula 
`(“Java Heap” – “Reserved Memory”) * spark.memory.fraction`

Just to give you an overview Storage Memory is This pool is used for both storing Apache Spark cached data and for temporary space serialized data “unroll”. Also all the “broadcast” variables are stored there as cached blocks

If you want to check total memory provided you can go to Spark UI `Spark-Master-Ip:8080`[default port] in the start you can find Section called `MEMORY` that is total memory used by spark.

Thanks

Comment: this formula???Java Heap(500MB) * spark.memory.fraction(default 0.6) * spark.memory.storyfraction(default 0.5)=150MB

Comment: this formula???  [Java Heap(500MB)-Reserved Memory(300MB)]*spark.memory.fraction(default 0.5)=100MB ≈ 110MB in my question

Comment: this formula is from spark version 1.6 might changed little bit

Comment: Your answer is very helpful to me

Answer (score 0):

From Spark 1.6 version, The memory is divided according to the following picture 
[image]

There is no hard boundary between execution and storage memory. The storage memory is required more then it takes from execution memory and viceversa. The 
**Execution and storage memory is given by (ExecutorMemory-300Mb)* spark.memory.fraction**

In your case (500-300)*).75 = 150mb there will be 3 to 5% error in Executor memory that is allocated.

**300Mb is the reserved memory**

**User memory = (ExecutorMemory-300)*).(1-spark.memory.fraction).**

In your case (500-300)*).25 = 50mb

[Java Memory : Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13988328/java-memory-runtime-getruntime-maxmemory/13988748#13988748)