# Display JVM used memory in megabytes/gigabytes

Tags: java

I have this code which displays the allocated JVM memory in (I suppose) bytes:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()
```

When I print the output I get something like `12232313131`. Can you tell me how I can print this in megabytes and gigabytes?

Comment: This post may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571203/what-is-the-exact-meaning-of-runtime-getruntime-totalmemory-and-freememory

Answer (score 3):

A nice trick is to use printf(...);

```
System.out.printf("%.3fGiB", Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() / (1024.0 * 1024.0 * 1024.0));
```

Comment: Those figures are GiB not GB, google it

Comment: I think that's a little more pedantic than the OP was expecting... I expect the OP was looking for GiB but still.... will edit post.

Comment: sorry don't want to be pendantic and I know that some programs do GB=1024 ** 3 but the official standard is now GB is 1000 ** 3, might as well get it right :)

Comment: @Vorsprung  GiB is usually used for ram/memory, and usually when you see GB in references to memory, it is actually GiB.

Comment: @nos I feel your pain but the IEEE have spoken http://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/binary.html

Comment: Scientifically correct but total nonsense for non-scientific purposes. GB has been what GiB is for years.

Comment: @Vorsprung The page you linked to says that 1 GiB is 1024*1024*1024 , which is exactly what the answer here calculates. And it says that 1 GB is 1000*1000*1000. So all is well, apparently.