# Compile java program using external jar file

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I working with standford core nlp packages. Which give set of jar files and execution unit. I could compile and run few test example.

There is one sample java example. 
I compiled is successfully with:

```
H:\Drive E\Stanford\stanfor-corenlp-full-2013~>javac -cp stanford-corenlp-3.3.0.
jar;stanford-corenlp-3.3.0-javadoc.jar;stanford-corenlp-3.3.0-models.jar;stanfor
d-corenlp-3.3.0-sources.jar; StanfordCoreNlpDemo.java
```

While I ran it:

```
H:\Drive E\Stanford\stanfor-corenlp-full-2013~>java -cp stanford-corenlp-3.3.0.
jar;stanford-corenlp-3.3.0-javadoc.jar;stanford-corenlp-3.3.0-models.jar;stanfor
d-corenlp-3.3.0-sources.jar; StanfordCoreNlpDemo
```

It gave exceptions:

```
Searching for resource: StanfordCoreNLP.properties
Searching for resource: edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/StanfordCoreNLP.properties
Adding annotator tokenize
Adding annotator ssplit
Adding annotator pos
Reading POS tagger model from edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3wo
rds/english-left3words-distsim.tagger ... done [8.7 sec].
Adding annotator lemma
Adding annotator ner
Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.all.3class.distsim.c
rf.ser.gz ... Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap s
pace
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$HandleTable.grow(ObjectInputStream.java:344
```

**How can I allocate memory in command line to remove above exception and execute it?**

I could compile these two successfully.

```
java -cp "*" -mx1g edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentPipeline -file input.txt
```

and

```
java -cp stanford-corenlp-3.3.0.jar;stanford-corenlp-3.3.0-models.jar;xom.jar;joda-time.jar -Xmx600m edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,parse -file input.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add this to your command line `-Xmx1024m` which will give 1GB of ram to your application, But I would rather advice you to use a java heap profiller like the one embedded in Netbeans [see here](https://profiler.netbeans.org/) to find out what's the real problem.
You can also refer to that post which has a much more complete explanation.
[What are Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() and freeMemory()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571203/what-is-the-exact-meaning-of-runtime-getruntime-totalmemory-and-freememory/3571231#3571231)

Comment: I already used netbeans, set memory `Xmx500,600,800,1000` but never succeed. Sometime no response for15-20 minutes, or exception for memory out of heap. googled a lot to any how get executed the example, but no luck

Comment: if you do face a `OutOfMemory` exception, it means that the example has a major memory leaks somewhere. try to use the memory profiler intgrated with netbeans to see what object are using so much RAM https://profiler.netbeans.org/

Comment: Give it **real** memory. `java -Xmx4g ...`

Answer (score 0):

I believe I am too late to answer your question, but this will definitely save somebody else's time that I took to figure out the execution of StanfordCoreNlpDemo.java file.

```
H:\Drive E\Stanford\stanfor-corenlp-full-2013~>java -cp stanford-corenlp-3.3.0.
jar;stanford-corenlp-3.3.0-javadoc.jar;stanford-corenlp-3.3.0-models.jar;stanfor
d-corenlp-3.3.0-sources.jar; -Xmx1200m StanfordCoreNlpDemo
```

For the Octoboer 2014 version of stanford-core-nlp, ';'(semicolon) should be replaced by ':'(colon)
It should be noted that there is a space needed in the last ';' and the -Xmx option in the above java command.