# JVM Memory for applet

Tags: java, applet, jvm

I have an applet and I need to increase his memory. If I pass this parameter:

```
    -Xmx=1024m
```

and execute this code:

```
    rt = Runtime.getRuntime()
    rt.maxMemory()/1024/1024
```

It returns **989M**

If I instead pass:

```
    -Xmx=2048m
```

It returns **154M**

Why is this, and how can I increase the maximum available memory for my Applet?

Comment: You didn't forget the `m` for the unit in the second parameter ? `-Xmx=2048m` instead of `-Xmx=2048` ?

Comment: No, I didn't forget. I have edited the post

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571203/what-is-the-exact-meaning-of-runtime-getruntime-totalmemory-and-freememory

Comment: hi Konstantin, I understand your post but no solves my issue. Why I can't set more than 1024M?

Comment: Read carefully. You need `totalMemory` not `maxMemory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xmx option you provide to limit JVM for max memory , now it is upto JVM how much memory it usages at Runtime. When you observed once it was 989M and the other time 154M, even it can go beyond also till it reaches Max Limit. You can not control how much memory applet will use other than giving max limit , JVM will control that.