# Hazelcast FREE_HEAP_PERCENTAGE policy not working as expected

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

Hazelcast's [`FREE_HEAP_PERCENTAGE`](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/manual/html/map-eviction.html#configuring-map-eviction) max size policy is not evicting map entries when the minimum configured free heap percentage on the JVM is met.

Below is a test case that illustrates this issue. If the test is run with other policy types (including `USED_HEAP_PERCENTAGE`), it works as expected such that entries are evicted when this max size is reached. However, if it is run with the `FREE_HEAP_PERCENTAGE`, entries are never evicted from the map, despite the fact that the free heap percentage is beyond the percentage allowed (as can be confirmed if running the management center, for example).

```
public class HazelcastMaxSizeTest {

    private static final String GROUP_NAME = "TEST";
    private static final String MAP_NAME = "test";

    private static MaxSizeConfig POLICY_THAT_WORKS = new MaxSizeConfig(5, MaxSizeConfig.MaxSizePolicy.USED_HEAP_PERCENTAGE);
    private static MaxSizeConfig POLICY_THAT_DOES_NOT_WORK = new MaxSizeConfig(99, MaxSizeConfig.MaxSizePolicy.FREE_HEAP_PERCENTAGE);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        HazelcastInstance instance = startHazelcast("hazelcast1", POLICY_THAT_DOES_NOT_WORK);
        System.out.println("started " + instance.getName());

        IMap<Long, byte[]> map = createMap(instance, MAP_NAME);
        System.out.println("map size: " + map.size());

        instance.shutdown();
    }

    private static HazelcastInstance startHazelcast(String instanceName, MaxSizeConfig maxSizeConfig) {

        MapConfig mapConfig = new MapConfig(MAP_NAME);
        mapConfig.setMaxSizeConfig(maxSizeConfig);
        mapConfig.setStatisticsEnabled(true);
        mapConfig.setEvictionPolicy(EvictionPolicy.LRU);
        mapConfig.setMinEvictionCheckMillis(0L);
        mapConfig.setBackupCount(1);

        Config config = new Config(instanceName);
        config.addMapConfig(mapConfig);
        config.getManagementCenterConfig().setEnabled(true);
        config.getManagementCenterConfig().setUrl("http://localhost:8080/mancenter");
        config.getGroupConfig().setName(GROUP_NAME).setPassword(GROUP_NAME);
        return Hazelcast.getOrCreateHazelcastInstance(config);
    }

    private static IMap<Long, byte[]> createMap(HazelcastInstance instance, String mapname) {

        IMap<Long, byte[]> map = instance.getMap(mapname);

        map.addEntryListener(new EntryEvictedListener<Long, byte[]>() {

            @Override
            public void entryEvicted(EntryEvent<Long, byte[]> event) {
                System.out.println("evicted " + event.getName() + ": " + event.getKey());
            }

        }, false);

        for (long i = 1; i <= 50_000; i++) {
            map.set(i, new byte[100]);
            if (i % 1000 == 0) {
                System.out.println("set " + map.getName() + ": " + i);
            }
        }

        return map;
    }

}
```

After some further debugging, I am wondering if Hazelcast's [`EvictionChecker`](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/v3.6/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/map/impl/eviction/EvictionCheckerImpl.java#L152-L157) may be incorrectly calculating free heap percentage. While debugging, I found that the calculated free heap percentage was greater than 100. It's calculation uses [`available / total`](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/v3.6/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/map/impl/eviction/EvictionCheckerImpl.java#L156), but as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571203/what-is-the-exact-meaning-of-runtime-getruntime-totalmemory-and-freememory#answer-18375641), this should perhaps be `available / max` instead?

Is there something wrong with my configuration or expected use of the `FREE_HEAP_PERCENTAGE` policy? Or is this a Hazelcast bug?

Specs: Hazelcast 3.6, `-Xmx256m`

Comment: what was your heap size? I used your test, set -Xmx256m, and it worked for me (can see evicted messages). BTW for testing purposes setting minEvictionCheckMillis to zero makes much sense, by setting it zero, eviction is checked whether it is doable upon every map#set.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited my question to use `0` for the `minEvictionCheckMillis` and specify `-Xmx256m` which does not work for me. I was finally able to get the `FREE_HEAP_PERCENTAGE` policy to evict some entries after significantly increasing the size of the map, however. What I don't understand, though, is that (1) if the `USED_HEAP_PERCENTAGE` is consistently met at 2% (and up to at least 5% or more), why is the `FREE_HEAP_PERCENTAGE` not reached at 99% (or even 100%)? (2) the management center showed ~30% heap usage percentage, so why would a policy requiring 99% free heap not be met?

Comment: After some further debugging, I am suspicious that Hazelcast may not be calculating the free heap correctly. I've updated my question accordingly.

Comment: When i checked the picture [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18375641/2269454), i can see that the calculated amount of free heap can be found with `max - (total - free)` and it is the equivalent of `max - total + free`, so [EvictionChecker](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/v3.6/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/map/impl/eviction/EvictionCheckerImpl.java#L152-L157) seems correct on this.

Comment: can you please elaborate on that, why are those in-equivalent?

Comment: I misread that. I think the problem is not with the calculation of available memory, but instead, the fact that the available memory is determined as a percentage of total memory, not max memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After further debugging, I found the unexpected behavior of the `FREE_HEAP_PERCENTAGE` policy was due to a bug in Hazelcast's calculation of the available memory. This issue has been reported as [Issue 7599](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/7599) in Hazelcast's issue tracker.