# Changing maximum java heap size

Tags: java, heap-size

As it is described in many sources I am trying to use `java -Xms512m` from the command line in order to set maximum size of heap for java machine to 512 Mb.
But something goes wrong and command line shows the following
[image]

And, as I checked directly from the program: 
`long heapMaxSize = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();`
heapMaxSize is equal to 954728448 which is about 1Gb.

Comment: Your image is huge. Please consider retaking the screen shot and uploading a smaller version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called a VM parameter, and must be specified when you start your VM (the JVM).

You may specify the maximum heap size as you run your program:

```
java -Xmx1024m -jar yourJar.jar
```

Or alternatively, you can set an environment variable on your system `JAVA_OPTS` and the JVM will respect your settings as it starts:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx1024m"
```

Regarding your second question, I would refer you to [What are Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() and freeMemory()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571203/what-is-the-exact-meaning-of-runtime-getruntime-totalmemory-and-freememory) as it clarifies what values are returned by `Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()` and friends.

Comment: Or add it do `JAVA_OPTS`, I think?

Comment: @erip I believe you are correct. I'll add that as well.

Comment: I'm not sure you can put -Xmx just after -jar

Comment: @NicolasFilotto fixed. typed too quick

Answer (score 1):

- `-Xmx<size>`: Max Size of the Java Heap (young generation + tenured generation)
- `-Xms<size>`: Initial Size of the Java Heap (young generation + tenured generation)
- `-Xmn<size>`: Size of the young generation Heap space

The problem that you face is not related to `-Xms`, it is due to the fact that your `java` command is incomplete, indeed you need to provide a jar with a main class defined in the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` or the FQN of the class to launch.