# Runime.getRuntime().totalMemory() and ActivityManager.MemoryInfo()

Tags: java, android, android-memory

Why total memory extracted from `getRuntime().totalMemory()` is not equal with when we use `ActivityManager.MemoryInfo()`? In below two code part I get different values:

```
long totalMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() ;
```

and

```
ActivityManager actManager = (ActivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                ActivityManager.MemoryInfo memInfo = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
                actManager.getMemoryInfo(memInfo);
                long totalMemory = memInfo.totalMem
```

in first code I get 12.759.040 and from the second code I get 907.034.624 !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#totalMemory--) is

> Returns the total amount of memory in the Java virtual machine. The value returned by this method may vary over time, depending on the host environment.

[`memInfo.totalMem`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.MemoryInfo.html#totalMem) is

> The total memory accessible by the kernel. This is basically the RAM size of the device, not including below-kernel fixed allocations like DMA buffers, RAM for the baseband CPU, etc.
>
> Note that the amount of memory required to hold an object of any given type may be implementation-dependent.

- The first one is the memory the jvm running your process holds, about 12 MB.
- The second one is the total kernel accessible system memory, about one gigabyte in your case.

The first is part of the second.

Answer (score 1):

Those are two different things.

> Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()

returns the total amount of memory in the Java Virtual Machine. This value can change over time. This is the runtime free memory.

> memInfo.totalMem

returns the total amount of available memory

You can consult these two SO topics:

[Topic 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571203/what-are-runtime-getruntime-totalmemory-and-freememory)

[Topic 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170691/how-to-get-current-memory-usage-in-android)

Comment: Thanks for two topics. Two topics are seen. Two useful topics.