# Available memory in Machine

Tags: java, memory, memory-management

Is there any way I could find out available or free ram in machine using Java ?

Need this detail so that I could launch my JVM accordingly.

Comment: [Not really](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552/get-os-level-system-information). You could try with some OS-specific way (like reading the output of `free` on linux).

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca, Lets say my JVM Max size for program is 2 GB. Any way I could check before hand that my JVM would be able to use atleast 2GB from available memory in machine  ? If its not available, I'll not launch my JVM

Comment: IMHO, just lunch the JVM and make it handle the lack of memory.

Comment: But wouldn't be a dangerous ?

Comment: take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571203/what-are-runtime-getruntime-totalmemory-and-freememory

Comment: There is a contradiction in our question. Getting the available RAM “using Java” doesn’t help when you want that number to “launch my JVM accordingly”.

Comment: @Holger, Please elaborate, how it contradicts ? JVM would lanch in RAM itself, No ?

Comment: To get the available RAM “using Java”, i.e. executing Java code, you need an already running JVM, which contradicts the purpose to specify these number *before* the JVM runs. When “JVM would launch in RAM itself” means to have two JVMs, well, that could work but surely is neither, simple nor efficient.

Comment: Anyway, it’s possible but the solution depends on the Java version. Which version do you use?

Comment: @Holger, 1.8 java version

Answer (score 2):

There is [an API allowing to get the numbers](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.management/com/sun/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html), but it’s not part of the official API in Java 8 and depends on an optional module, `jdk.management`, in JDK 11.

You can use dynamic access to avoid direct code dependencies to unofficial APIs. In the common implementations, i.e. OpenJDK and Oracle’s JDK distribution, it will be available:

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import javax.management.*;

public class Memory {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JMException {
        MBeanServer mBeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
        ObjectName objectName = new ObjectName("java.lang:type=OperatingSystem");

        Long free = (Long)mBeanServer.getAttribute(objectName, "FreePhysicalMemorySize");
        Long total= (Long)mBeanServer.getAttribute(objectName, "TotalPhysicalMemorySize");

        final double gb = 0x1p-30;

        System.out.printf("%.2f GB of %.2f GB free%n", free * gb, total * gb);

        total = (Long)mBeanServer.getAttribute(objectName, "TotalSwapSpaceSize");
        free  = (Long)mBeanServer.getAttribute(objectName, "FreeSwapSpaceSize");

        System.out.printf("%.2f GB of %.2f GB swap free%n", free * gb, total * gb);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it static ? "java.lang:type=OperatingSystem"

Comment: It’s [this constant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.OPERATING_SYSTEM_MXBEAN_NAME). When I wrote the answer, it just slipped my mind that these strings also have corresponding named constants you can use. So instead of `"java.lang:type=OperatingSystem"`, you can also write `ManagementFactory.OPERATING_SYSTEM_MXBEAN_NAME`.

Comment: Is it a good practice using linux command free -h to get free ram using java code  ? In case of Initialising JVM in linux.

Comment: That would be more of an [operating system question](https://superuser.com/tour)…